# How do I get the AD group and add users to it?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I haven't done this in so long and I simply want to get the group `CoreControls` and add a user or another group. How do I write the `FindByIdentity`? It always return null. The domain is `crp.name.local`

[image]

```
using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(
    ContextType.Domain,
    "crp",
    username,
    password))
{
    // group is null and I've tried many examples...
    var group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, "ou=CoreControls");
    group.Members.Add(pc, IdentityType.UserPrincipalName, userId);
    group.Save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is `CoreControls` is not actually a group, but an OU.  So you cannot use `GroupPrincipal` here.  Try this `PrincipalContext` overload instead:

```
using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(
    ContextType.Domain,
    "crp",
    "OU=CoreControls,OU=Security,OU=Global Groups,DC=crp,DC=local"
    username,
    password))
```

You will have to fiddle with the `container` parameter to get it just right.